# Count the number of objects in HBASE and to email the count

Tags: hbase, couchbase

I am new to HBASE
1.How can i get the count of number of objects in HBASE 
and
2.want to store that count in sql server database
Can anyone help me?

Thanks & Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 1):

Count rows in HBase is not easy like in SQL databases, you will need to create a MapReduce job and to run it, and will take a little bit of time.

You can do it from the HBase shell with the command

```
count 'tableName'
```

or running the job with hadoop:

```
hadoop jar hbase.jar rowcount
```

After that (you can call it through a shell script, and will return the partial count while running, see [HBase wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Shell)), and write it to a local file, then read it and save it in a SQL database or everywhere.

If your application is just on one node and it's the only modifier, you can just use a counter managed internally (an integer increased when you add a row and decreased when you delete one) to avoid the problem.

Comment: Hi thank u for the answer and now how can i write it or save it??
And I am connecting the HBASe through putty and SQL server Database is in another Server ... any help?

Comment: If you want to write it programmatically you can create a bash script with the command
*hadoop jar hbase.jar rowcount>countresult.txt* to save the result in a file. Then read that file with Java or within the script itself to extract the last line and save it in the database. In Java you'll need a JDBC connector and there you'll specify the database hostname, the fact that is on another machine should not be a problem.

Comment: Ok i will try with this,, but if there is any code(already developed) is appreciated.. which will really help me! thank you JACKOPO

Comment: You should tell us more, for example in which DBMS you want to save it, how often, how many nodes are there in the cluster and how heavy is the load and the concurrent access to HBase.

Comment: Sql Server 2008r2 database i want to save it and about concurrent users are less than 10 i suppose as we are connecting remotely.